# Количество предикативных частей в предложении

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор, основа

> Князь Андрей, думавший, что ему было все равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так, как взяли Смоленск, внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.

В этом предложении 4 предикативные части?

- главная - *"князь Андрей внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло"*
- 1 придаточная - *"что ему было всё равно"*
- 2 придаточная - *"возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву так"*
- 3 придаточная - *"как взяли Смоленск"*

Comment: А Вам, по-моему, уже ответили на этот вопрос, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере 4 предикативных частей: 3 придаточных: **что ему было всё равно, возьмут ли или не возьмут Москву,** **как взяли Смоленск. И главная часть: князь Андрей внезапно остановился в своей речи от неожиданной судороги, схватившей его за горло.**

Comment: Я не пойму, а главная часть разве не входит в понятие предикативных частей?
Думала, что считаются все: главные части и придаточные

Comment: Простите, конечно четыре. Я спутал с придаточными предложениями.

Answer (score 1):

> Сколько предикативных частей в предложении? 4?

Конечно, **четыре**: одна -- в главном предложении, три -- в придаточных.

Comment: спасибо вам большое!